# Job listing platform - Search function

Tags: javascript, html, database, frontend

I am a self taught CS student and I am currently implementing a job listing website. I am almost done with the front-end part and I am starting the back-end part this week (probably Node + Mongo DB but I have no idea). I did implement a search function with JavaScript yesterday but it is filtering elements based on what I have on my HTML code (a list of jobs). It is working but I am wondering if I am doing this correctly of I should filter the jobs directly on the database and then display the matches ?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="job-board">
    <li class="job job-1">
        <div class="job-title">
            <h2>Process Engineer</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="job-location">
            <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
        </div>
        <div class="job-type">
                <p>Type: Full-Time</p>
        </div>
        <div class="job-date">
                <p>Published on 07/19/2019</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="job job-2">
            <div class="job-title">
                <h2>Chief Financial Officier</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="job-location">
                <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
            </div>
            <div class="job-type">
                    <p>Type: Full-Time</p>
            </div>
            <div class="job-date">
                    <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="job job-3">
                <div class="job-title">
                    <h2>Assistant CEO</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="job-location">
                    <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
                </div>
                <div class="job-type">
                        <p>Type: Part-Time</p>
                </div>
                <div class="job-date">
                        <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="job job-4">
                    <div class="job-title">
                        <h2>Front-End Developer</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="job-location">
                        <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="job-type">
                            <p>Type: Part-Time</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="job-date">
                            <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
                    </div>
                </li>          
</ul>
```

[User Interface for search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKu9w.png)

Comment: I'm not an expert in any way, but since you didn't receive an answer in the last hour I dare to leave a comment. From the phasing of your question it seems that "jobs list" is hardcoded in the page. That would mean to rewrite the code for new jobs. The way to go (if I correctly interpret you) would be to have the data in a database, filtering required items server-side, and pass only required data to client. But your question is too vague for being understandable (not to say to answer...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it is hardcoded because I was workinf on the front-end part. But what I want to do is to be able to add new job listing directly from the database. I am not sure between MYSQL or MongoDB

Comment: Can't help  you with that. As I said, I'm not an expert. I've worked extensively with mysql, but do not know anything about mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Well to be honest not an expert on nosql database (e.g. MongoDb), but from what I hear they are great for storing and retrieving by key, but if you want to do more complex stuff you might be better off with relational one (e.g. MySql). Say get me j*obs by category* or *published after some date*. In MongoDb you will need to load **every** item from DB to check the category/date, while relational has some optimalizations to only check given column. In your case I would go with relational I think.

About where to do the filtering. I think a good practice is to try to transmit as little data as possible. Say you have **Frontend**, your JavaScript code that runs on client, than **Backend** code (node.js in your case) that runs on the server and finally **DB**. Now, if you filter on frontend that means you get all the data including the ones you will filter out from DB to backend and then from backend to **every** client's frontend. So depending on how much "extra" data and concurent users you have, this can be quite a waste. That results in frontend app being less responsive and so on of course. So I would go for filtering directly in DB probably, but backend is OK as well.

Another benefit on having it on backend (or DB) enables you to do fancy caching and such optimalizations to avoid going to DB (because retrieving data from DB is usually quite slow) that other clients get on the first call for free.

BTW what are you using for frontend if you don't mind me asking? It seems like just HTML + JavaScript. In that case I would suggest to check out some of these fancy frontend libraries like React or Angular. I tried them out recently myself and was impress how much easier they make the frontend development nowadays.

Sorry for such a long rambling, please let me know if it was not clear or what you asked for. Good luck:)